# Javascript/Jquery alternative to "display:none"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a menu that shows or hides content when you click menu items. The JQuery looks like this:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

    $("#bioLink").click(function(){
        $("#about").show(1000);
        $("#portfolio, #contact, #expand").hide(1000);
    }); // end bio-click
    $("#portfolioLink").click(function(){
        $("#portfolio").show(1000);;
        $("#about, #contact, #expand").hide(1000);
    }); // end portfolio-click
    $("#contactLink").click(function(){
        $("#contact").show(1000);
        $("#about, #portfolio, #expand").hide(1000);
    }); // end contact-click
}); // end ready
```

In an older version of the site, all content is hidden when the page first loads, with this CSS rule:

```
    #about, #portfolio, #contact {
        display:none;
}
```

That CSS now wreaks havoc with [a carousel](http://dbpas.github.io/dbpasCarousel/) I have since installed in the portfolio section.

Is there something I can do with the script to hide the content upon loading? Given that the existing script doesn't interfere with the carousel, this could be a proper solution.

Comment: it probably wreaks havoc with a carousel  because display: none; not only hides the element but gets rid of the space it took on the page. Try visibility:hidden; which does not -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp -- check these demos to see the difference -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_display_none -- http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_visibility_hidden

Comment: sounds like an XY-problem. A carousel shouldn't affect the rest of the page. Something wrong in the page structure somewhere

Answer (score 0):

There's several options to hide content on a page.

```
display: none;
```

This is the one you're currently uses, which collapses content (i.e. the element doesn't take up any space on the page.

```
visibility: hidden;
```

This hides content, but doesn't collapse, so the element while not visible still takes up the same amount of space on the page (useful if you want to hide and show elements in a list or navbar without making things jump back and forth).

```
opacity: 0;
```

Similar to visibility hidden, but still allows a user to trigger events or tab to the element.

There's a couple others, but these are the main three that would be useful.  Would you mind elaborating on the wreaking havoc part?  It's a bit difficult to provide you with the right tools given the problem is a bit vague.

Comment: hiding the elements upon loading causes the carousel window to display maybe a tenth of the normal width, and the scrolling doesn't seem to work either. I've tried tinkering with the CSS for the plugin, but it hasn't even been cooperative enough for me to know what questions to ask about it.

Comment: Is there any way you could post a link to your site?  If not, is the carousel nested or do you have duplicate IDs?  Can you change #portfolio to something more specific that wouldn't affect the carousel?

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize the content IDs to be initially hidden on document load like this:

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $( "#about, #portfolio, #contact" ).hide();
   });
```

Then let the conditional script follow this to show and hide as ordered by the click event. Initializing the hide allows for other things to work without your script trying to run at the same time. <-- not sure if I explained that correctly

Comment: This is what I was looking for, but it seems to do the same nasty things to the carousel as the CSS rule did, which puts me at square one.

Comment: Have you tried moving this script to the bottom of the page to allow for your carousel to run first? And  Have you tried a noConflict.js?

Comment: this is a poor replacement for what OP already had in css....have to wait for dom ready before it kicks in whereas css won't let it be displayed right away

Comment: LOTUSMS: simply moving the carousel script ahead of the script that hides things seems to have fixed it. I have some more things I need to organize on the site, so I'm not celebrating before I see the whole thing in action, but the things that can go wrong from here on out look...reduced.

Comment: @JohnnyEngine. Great! That's why I suggested to move the script to the bottom of the page. That makes the carousel run first because it is the scritp that gets hit first. Glad I helped. I think you'll be alright